# Как сохранить два файла (video.mp4 и thumb.png) с одним именем?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Загружаю видео и эскиз с этого видео на сервер, нужно сохранить обa файлы с одним именем.

чтобы для обе файла получилось название примерно: **123.png** и **123.mp4**

Но, обязательно случайный и уникальный название.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1000M');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$video_thumb_name = uniqid('video_', true);

if (isset($_REQUEST['saveCanvas'])) {
    $img       = $_POST['imgBase64'];
    $img       = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img       = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data      = base64_decode($img);
    $fileThumb = $video_thumb_name . '.png';
    $success   = file_put_contents('thumbnails/'.$fileThumb, $data);
    print $success ? $fileThumb : 'Unable to save the file.';
}
$return['status'] = 0;
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $name        = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $extension   = explode('.', $name);
    $extension   = end($extension);
    $type        = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $size        = $_FILES['file']['size'] / 1024 / 1024;
    $tmp         = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $videoName   = $video_thumb_name . '.' . $extension;

    if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4") {
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/' . $videoName);
        $return['videoName'] = $videoName;
        $return['thumbName'] = $fileThumb;
        $return['status']    = 1;
    }
    echo json_encode($return);
}
sleep(1);
?>
```

Сделал так...

No названии не совпадают.

Нужно остановить генерация названий **$video_thumb_name = uniqid('video_', true);** при первом обращение, а то разница времени...

Результат на ftp: **video_5baf1495b60328.59934882.mp4** и **video_5baf149a72c682.53232850.png**

**---------------------------------------**

Еще один вопрос/проблема:

```
$return['thumbName'] = $fileThumb;
```

Здесь получаю **null**

---

JS в index.php:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha384-FzT3vTVGXqf7wRfy8k4BiyzvbNfeYjK+frTVqZeNDFl8woCbF0CYG6g2fMEFFo/i" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
function getThumb(video, thumbnailname) {
    maxWidth = 700;
    maxHeight = 700;
    var w = video.videoWidth;
    var h = video.videoHeight;
    if (w >= h) {
        var ratio = 1 / (w / maxWidth);
    } else {
        var ratio = 1 / (h / maxHeight);
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = w * ratio;;
    canvas.height = h * ratio;;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w * ratio, h * ratio);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload_video.php?saveCanvas=1",
        data: {
            imgBase64: document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL('image/png')
        }
    }).done(function(o) {
        console.log(0);
    });
}
jQuery('#myForm').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var percent = jQuery('.percent');
    jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit({
        url: 'upload_video.php',
        beforeSend: function() {
            var percentVal = '0%';
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            jQuery("#myf1_upload_process, #divLoading").css("visibility", "visible");
            jQuery("#file_browse_wrapper").css("visibility", "hidden");
            var percentVal = 'Uploaded: ' + percentComplete + '%';
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        success: function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
            //status.html(xhr.responseText);            
            var loaded = false;
            var videos = xhr.videoName;
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            //video.src = 'videos/' + videos;
            video.src = videos;
            video.load();

            video.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
                this.currentTime = this.duration / 15;
            }, false);

            saved = false;
            setInterval(function() {
                if (!saved) {
                    var thumbnailname = xhr.thumbName;
                    if (video.readyState >= 3) {
                        saved = true;
                        getThumb(video, thumbnailname);
                        jQuery("#myeditor").val(videos + '\n' + thumbnailname + '.png');
                        jQuery("#myf1_upload_process, #divLoading").css("visibility", "hidden");
                        jQuery("#file_browse_wrapper").css("visibility", "visible");
                        jQuery("#myf1_upload_form").html('<br /> <input id="file_browse" type="file" name="file" accept="video/mp4" size="0" style="cursor:pointer" /><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" class="mysbtn" value="Upload Image" />');
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
    return true;
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Если вопрос в уникальном имени, то к примеру используйте значение time(), соответственно значение будет уникальным + можно будет определить время записи

Comment: Спасибо за совет, тоже буду пробовать. Добавил: **uniqid('video_', true);** Главный вопрос: **Как сохранить обе файла с одним именем.** Пока не получается :(

Comment: Ввиду того что функция time() в разные периоды времени разнаю, присвойте вначале ее значение переменной, а уже после назначайте имя видео файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для генерирования уникального имени файла rand() не подходит, лучше воспользоваться [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uniqid.php) с параметром more_entropy. А для того чтобы переменная была видна в обоих условиях её надо вынести наружу, например после `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: **@Ivan Chaykin** Поправил мой первый пост, пожалуйста посмотрите что там не так.

Comment: Результат выполнения скрипта: `{"status":1,"videoName":"video_5baea3bbbc90e4.42089451.mp4","thumbName":"video_5baea3bbbc90e4.42089451.png"}`. 
Приведите ваш результат. И советую всё же исправить способ генерации уникального имени примерно на такой:
`$video_thumb_name = uniqid('video_', true);`

Comment: **@Ivan Chaykin** Исправил по вашему совету. Результат: **video_5baf1495b60328.59934882.mp4** и **video_5baf149a72c682.53232850.png**

Comment: Так ну смотрите, переменной `$video_thumb_name` присваивается значение при запуске скрипта, на протяжении работы скрипта эта переменная не переопределяется. Прихожу к выводу, что сохранение картинки и сохранение видео вы делаете двумя разными запросами к этому скрипту. Из-за этого у вас и `$fileThumb` во втором условии null, так как переменная инициируется в первом условии и не видна из второго. Можно подробнее о том, как вы обращаетесь к этому скрипту?

Comment: Да, делаеться двумя разными запросами. Для эскиза: **function getThumb(video, thumbnailname) { ... url: "upload_video.php?saveCanvas=1"**. Для видео уже в другом функцие: **jQuery('#myForm').on('change', function(e) {... url: 'upload_video.php'**. Cразу передавать название не получится?

Comment: Нужно либо объединить оба действия в один запрос, либо в getThumb передавать полученное при сохранении видео имя, оно возвращается в ответе в формате json

Comment: У меня не получается :( А если сделаю так: **$fileThumb = $videoName . '.png';** (Буду резать **type**), но только как передавать? Или все равно будет разница в обращение?

Comment: А вам принципиально чтобы загрузка видео и сохранение картинки были именно разными запросами?

Comment: Еще один вариант, может полегче получится тут? [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550624/without-onchange-file-uploader-php-not-working-correctly)

Comment: Попробуйте, возможно это для вас будет легче. А касательно вашего основного вопроса, сложно понять какие запросы вы отправляете и какие данные они содержат. Листинг функции getThumb и jQuery('#myForm') приложите.

Comment: Добавил в первом посте.

Comment: Вот теперь всё прояснилось =) Функция getThumb принимает thumbnailname но не как его не обрабатывает. Нужно в getThumb исправить `$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload_video.php?saveCanvas=1",
            data: {
                imgBase64: document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL('image/png'),
                thumbnailName: thumbnailname
            }`. А в upload_video.php, в условии где сохраняете изображение присвоить переменной $fileThumb значение переданное функцией getThumb `$fileThumb = $_POST['thumbnailName'] . '.png';`

Comment: Ну и `$return['thumbName'] = $fileThumb;` поменять на `$return['thumbName'] = $video_thumb_name;` во втором условии

Comment: Еще проблема :( Если без перезагрузки страницы загрузить ишо один видео, сохраняется уже с другим именем.

Comment: То есть, миниатюра была создана с уже использованным именем.